# Получить глобальную переменную после проверки в Python

Tags: python

Проверяю description на отсутствие пустых строк, что бы не было ответа, как [ ]:

```
[ ]  
[ ]  
[ ]  
-=VPNs=-  
Internet
```

Как проверку description при условии совпадения приравнять к глобальной переменной? То есть после проверки я хочу работать с этими непустыми переменными...
Если `print(description)` сделать слева без отступа, то появляется ответ от `description = re.findall(r"description\s+(\S[\s\S]*\S)", line)`.
Мне необходимо в глобальном print(description) получить -=VPNs=- и Internet. И только их, а не с пустыми данными [ ]
То есть необходимо в будущем работать с проверенной переменной. Смог описать проблему?)

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

text = """
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 match source-address any
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term01 then permit
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term10 match
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term11 description -=VPNs=-
set security policies from-zone untrust to-zone nprch policy term100 description Internet
"""

policies = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for line in text.strip().splitlines():
    description = re.findall(r"description\s+(\S[\s\S]*\S)", line)
    if description:
      print(*description)
```

Comment: Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Не что в коде написано, а что вам нужно. "Вот данные, такой нужен результат, написал так-то, получилось так-то.". В вопросе должны быть все четыре пункта.

Comment: мне нужно в глобальном print(description) получить -=VPNs=- и Internet. И только их, а не с пустыми данными [ ]

Comment: Внесите правки **в вопрос**, пожалуйста.

Comment: После `findall` пишете `if description: print(*description)` и всё,  вместо последних трёх строк

Comment: @CrazyElf исправил (упростил). Но как не пустой description далее сделать глобальным?

Comment: Ну сделайте до цикла список `all_descriptions = []`, а там где нашли не пустой список делайте `all_descriptions.extend(description)` и будут у вас после всей обработки в `all_descriptions` все не пустые описания. В принципе, там можно даже не проверять, что `description` не пустой список, из пустого списка ничего просто не добавится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете накапливать элементы в дополнительном списке, используя метод `extend`, добавляющий в список все элементы другого списка:

```
all_descriptions = []
for line in text.strip().splitlines():
    description = re.findall(r"description\s+(\S[\s\S]*\S)", line)
    all_descriptions.extend(description)
print(all_descriptions)
```

Comment: Благодарю, работает